# Wordpress Cannot display correctly index page header image

Tags: css, wordpress, header, banner

on a friend's site , I am trying to help him display correctly the index page banner. The used theme is Arcade Basic (Batovasan)

The image uploaded in the library is 1920x500px (150dpi) , the generated html code is :

```
<header id="header">
    <div class="title-card-wrapper">
         <div class="title-card" style="height: 778px;">
            <img class="header-img" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/myHeader.jpg" alt="" style="position: absolute; left: -667px; top: 0px; right: auto; bottom: auto; width: auto; height: 100%;">
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

the image is automatically set as enlarged with an auto negative left position...   ( see http://www.tangoumois.com )

the current css is

```
.title-card {
  position: relative; }

.title-card-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden; }

.title-card {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  text-align: center; }
  .title-card > img.header-img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    left: -9999px;
    max-width: none; }
```

and in the function.php, there is a filter to upload and resize the image

```
// Add a filter to bavotasan_header_image_width and bavotasan_header_image_height to change the width and height of your custom header.
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', array(
    'header-text' => false,
    'flex-height' => true,
    'flex-width' => true,
    'random-default' => false,
    'width' => apply_filters( 'bavotasan_header_image_width', 1920 ),
    'height' => apply_filters( 'bavotasan_header_image_height', 500 ),
) );
```

when I check it with Chrome Dev, I get the following

[image: calculated box sizing]

How can I set correctly the banner , without this negative positions ..

Answer (score 0):

Remove `left: -9999px;` from this block on chane it on `left: 0;` (better to remove)

```
      .title-card > img.header-img {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 0;
        left: -9999px;
        max-width: none; }
```

Comment: thanks
left: 0 is fine but this does not change anything in the resizing...
I guess Burhan ( below) is given us some good hints... 
I would like to have my banner as any other page header banner ( they all have the same size) but the theme is trying to use it as a background... ( it's enlarged a lot...)

Answer (score 0):

So you are using the image inside the  tag, while you are attempting to have it in the background layer,

So my basic solution for you is to change a bit of code, delete the  line,
Go to css and do this:

```
#site-meta{
    background: url(http://www.tangoumois.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Bannière-PageActualité.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Image > https://image.ibb.co/jpZQJv/Capture.png
 Description :

if you want to have an image in the background of the div, you must do it with css using ( background:url('');..

If you want to keep using it with the image tag, you should change your div height to equal the image height so you can avoid the spaces..

Comment: you change the ( .title-card height to     height: 565px;) then you can have it done.

Comment: thanks a lot this it it...  I'm not a WP expert , neither CSS ( background API dev, dev ..  only basic UI & CSS knowledge, but learning a lot from guys like you !!!

Answer (score 0):

You have many unnecessary CSS styles. Also, it's probably better to use background-image than img in this case.

Comment: sure... but it's not mine CSS... done by the theme dev, I also prefer coding raw HTML5 + CSS3...  whatever I've to deal with it...  ;-))